# Testing method with dependency on File class and other methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, methods, moq

So I created a CsvParser to read a content of a file and parse each line/row of that file. I have the following logic:

```
public interface ICsvReader {
    List<string> ReadFromFile(string path);
}

public class CsvReader : ICsvReader 
{
    private readonly ICsvParser _csvParser;
    
    public CsvReader(ICsvParser csvParser) 
    {
        _csvParser = csvParser;
    }
    
    public List<string> ReadFromFile(string path) 
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path)) return null;

        var content = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        return ParseContent(content);
    }
    
    private List<string> ParseContent(StreamReader input) 
    {
        List<string> rows = new List<string>();
        foreach (var line in lines) {
            var updatedRow = _csvParser.ParseRow(line);
            lines.Add(updatedRow);
        }

        return rows;
    }
}

public interface ICsvParser 
{
    string ParseRow(string row);
}

public CsvParser : ICsvParser 
{
    public string ParseRow(string row) 
    {
       // Performing parsing here returning parsed row
    }
}
```

This works, however needs tests to be written for it. This is where I am having issues and some confusion about how to approach this. Firstly my code is coupled/ dependant on the File class, so surely in testing it will try to use real data which is not ideal. I was thinking of using a mock to pass in fake data but not sure how that would work. I'm not too familiar with moq but I am assuming I would want to create a mock to pass test data into ReadFromFile and check the expected outcome is correct?

Secondly I have used dependency injection to remove the dependency between CsvReader and CsvParser specifically the ParseRow method. I know I can use moq to mock the interface + method however since PraseRow is being called in a foreach loop how will this affect the setup? In other words the return value will be different each time it is called?

Comment: 1. abstract file system access and avoid tightly coupling to implementation concerns. 2. Use either SetupSequence or function delegate in Returns when setting up the mock for reader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstly my code is coupled/ dependant on the File class

As a general rule, try to write APIs that can take a *stream* as input. You can have an additional method that takes a file-path, open the file and forward the stream to the other method. But that is mostly for convenience. APIs that only takes filepaths are super annoying when you have a memory stream or some other source of the data and is forced to save it to a temporary file.

If the method that takes a file-path contains little logic, the benefit of unit-testing it is less. If it only opens a file I would be satisfied by just a code review. Not every line of code needs to be covered by unit tests. Or rather, the benefit/cost ratio of unit tests varies a lot depending on what kind of code it is.

> surely in testing it will try to use real data which is not ideal

I do not think unit tests with real data is necessarily bad. Sure, if the amount of data is tiny it might be better to simply use a hardcoded string or byte array as the source for the test-data. But it might also be useful add a larger and more complex file as a content-file in your test project and write a test using that file. This will slow down the unit tests somewhat. If that is a problem, a solution can be to put tests using IO in a special category that is run less frequently.

> I know I can use moq to mock the interface + method however since PraseRow is being called in a foreach loop how will this affect the setup?

You can still test the two classes together if you want. For classes like this I would probably consider them so strongly coupled that testing them separately would not add much benefit. I.e. you should consider if the benefit of testing them separately outweighs the additional cost.

> In other words the return value will be different each time it is called?

It is up to you. Writing a mock that returns the same value each time is easier. But it should be perfectly possible to return lines from a list if you want to.